# Proof that path lifting function is continuous in a local fibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question is about the proof of the following theorem in "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" by J.P. May (page 52):

> Let $p:E\to B$ be a map and let $\mathcal{O}$ be a numerable open cover of $B$. Then $p$ is a fibration if and only if $p:p^{-1}(U)\to U$ is a fibration for every $U\in \mathcal{O}$

My confusion is with the "if" direction. May's proof goes roughly as follows: We define maps $\lambda_U:B\to I$ satisfying $\lambda_U^{-1}(0,1]=U$ (this can be done from our "numerable" assumption). For each finite ordered subset $T=\{U_1,...,U_n\}$,  of sets in $\mathcal{O}$, we define $c(T)=n$ and define $\lambda_T:B^I\to I$ by
$$\lambda_T(\beta)=\inf \{(\lambda_{U_i}  \circ \beta ) (t) : (i-1)/n \le t \le i/n , 1\le i\le n \}.$$
We then define $W_T=\lambda_T^{-1}(0,1]$, making $\{W_T\}$ an open cover of $B^I$. Defining the maps $\gamma_T:B^I\to I$ by
$$\lambda_T (B) = \max \{ 0,\lambda_T (B) - n \sum _{c(S)<c(T)} \lambda_S (\beta )\}$$
we can define
$$V_T=\{\beta|\gamma_T(\beta)>0\}\subset W_T,$$
making $\{V_T\}$ a locally finite open cover of $B^I$. We choose a total ordering of the set of all finite ordered subsets $T$ of $\mathcal{O}$. We choose path lifting functions
$$s_U : p^{-1} (U) \times _p U^I \rightarrow p^{-1} (U) ^I $$
for each $U\in \mathcal O$, preparing us to construct the global path lfting function.

For a given $T=\{U_1,...,U_n\}$, consider paths $\beta\in V_T$. For $0\leq u<v\leq 1$, let $\beta[u,v]$ be the restriction of $\beta$ to $[u,v]$. We define $s_T(e,\beta[u,v])$ canonically, by lifting one interval at a time using the local path lifting functions.

Now we define our global path lifting function. For each $(e,\beta)\in E\times_p B^I$, we define the $s(e,\beta)$ to be the concatenation of the paths $s_{T_j}(e_{j-1},\beta[u_{j-1},u_j])$, $1\leq j\leq q$, where the $T_i$, in order, run through the set of all $T$ such that $\beta\in V_T$, where $u_0=0$ and $u_j=(\sum_{i=1}^j\gamma_{T_i}(\beta))/(\sum_{i=1}^q\gamma_{T_i}(\beta))$, where $e_0=e$ and $e_j$ is the endpoint of $s_{T_j}(e_{j-1},\beta[u_{j-1},u_j])$ for $1\leq j\leq q$.

My problem is with the statement that it's "not hard" to check that $s$ is continuous, and I'm in fact having a lot of trouble checking this part. I tried the following:

We can interpret the path lifts $s$ as maps $(E\times_p B^I)\times I\to E$, and the local path lifts $s_U$ as maps $(p^{-1}(U)\times_p U^I)\times I\to p^{-1}(U)$. It suffices to prove that $s$ written this way is continuous. So let $U' \subset E$ be open, and let $((e,\beta),t)\in s^{-1}(U')$. I have tried working backwards along each subpath of $s$ to eventually find a neighborhood of $((e,\beta ),t)$ that maps into $U'$, but I'm getting stuck. One of my issues is in knowing what open sets of $E\times_p B^I$ look like, since the topology of $E\times_p B^I$ is actually the $k$-ification of $E\times_p B^I$ with the canonical topology.

Does it look like I'm headed in the right direction? If not, is there a more concise proof?